# Separate style for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I want to create a separate styles (or stylesheet) for iOS / Android / Windows mobile etc...

**How can I recognise the mobile device and apply a different style to it?**
I don't wan't to use detection by screen resolution.

Basically I want to hide an element on mobile devices:

```
<div class="nomobile"> QWERTY </div>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      $('.nomobile').addClass('.hide');
        }
      else{
      $('.nomobile').removeClass('.hide');            
      }
</script>
```

And css:

```
<style>
 .nomobile.hide {display:none;}
</style>
```

Unfortunately something is wrong with this code, as it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of JS libraries to do that on Internet. I recommend [is.js](http://is.js.org/)

**EDIT**

Ok, here is a possible use of **is.js** to fit your need. You need to test the snippet on a real mobile device, because the function `is.mobile()` do the detection by combination of the OS, Browser and Screen of the device, that means the code will not work over Responsive Design View of desktop browsers!

```js
if(is.mobile()) {
    $('.nomobile').addClass('.hide');
}else{
    $('.nomobile').removeClass('.hide');
}
```

```css
<style>
 .nomobile.hide {display:none;}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/is_js/0.9.0/is.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nomobile"> QWERTY </div>
```

Comment: Thank Yulio. Can you please help me understand how to implement this? I found the function:

is.mobile();
=> true if current device is mobile

But not sure how to use it.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski review the update on my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not looking to use CSS, would something like this work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if (screen.width < 960) {
$('.nomobile').addClass('.hide');
}
else {
$('.nomobile').removeClass('.hide');            
}
});
```

Comment: Bob, I mentioned "I don't wan't to use detection by screen resolution", so this is not an option

Answer (score -1):

With this "magical" CSS instruction into which you can insert rules for classes if the size condition is satisfied...

```
@media screen and (max-width:300px){

 .someclass {display:none}  // an example of making something disappear if screen is too small

}
```

NB: So adjust the "300px" to whatever dimensions you need.

Comment: I mentioned "I don't wan't to use detection by screen resolution", so this is not an option –